# How to display json schema using Dataweave in Mule 4?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

in Mule 4 I just want to display the JSONschema using DataWeave but I get an error for reference ids or any field started with '$' in JSON schema. The mime/type is application/json. The goal is to display the schema, I'll appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

SAMPLE SCHEMA

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "properties": {
    "checked": {
      "$id": "/properties/checked",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Checked Schema",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        false
      ]
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "$id": "/properties/dimensions",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Dimensions Schema",
      "required": [
        "width",
        "height"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "width": {
          "$id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/width",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The Width Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            5
          ]
        },
        "height": {
          "$id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/height",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The Height Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            10
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "id": {
      "$id": "/properties/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Id Schema",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        1
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use blackslash `\` before $, this will print your schema with $ in column names. Unfortuanely, $ as a prefix is not treated as part of string in Mule

Example

`"\$id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/width"`

will print

```
"$id": "/properties/dimensions/properties/width"
```